# Is Self Signed Cert multiples URL working fine in iOS 9

Tags: https, ios9

I am using `NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:"https://mytest.com/19"]`

and allow `[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL host]];`
so manually login ..
Please let me know if i have multiples URL then how can    ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can opt out security for all domains once by keeping above falg in info.plist Hope it can help you.

Comment: hanks @Nookaraju .. this is the solution of iOS 9.0 App Transport Security .i am not asking about it...  i am giving you examples likes using NSString stringWithFormat:"https://10.234.234.82/MyAPP  and using another url is https://10.234.43.80/MyApp how can i login  with multiples url ..thats asking about

Answer (score 1):

try this work for me:-

```js
NSString *strURL1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://32ewwrwrwerw/bxbbx/"];
    NSString *strURL2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://demo1/demo/"];
    NSString *strURL3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://demo2.com/demo2/"];
    NSString *strURL4=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://demo3.com/demo3/"];
    NSString *strURL5=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xvxylsl.com/demo4/"];
    
    
    NSURL *URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL1];
    NSURL *URL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL2];
    NSURL *URL3 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL3];
    NSURL *URL4 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL4];
    NSURL *URL5 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL5];




    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL1 host]];
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL2 host]];
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL3 host]];
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL4 host]];
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL5 host]];
```

```
 NSString *strURL1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xcxcxc/121w321"];
 NSString *strURL2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xbxnjkx/wjdjd/"];
 NSString *strURL3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://jwkjsjs/bxbxb/"];    
 NSString *strURL4=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://10.11.22.11/ggsgs/"];    
 NSString *strURL5=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://10.23.234.122/hhdd/"];

NSURL *URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL1];
NSURL *URL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL2];
NSURL *URL3 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL3];
NSURL *URL4 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL4];
NSURL *URL5 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL5];




[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL1 host]];
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL2 host]];
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL3 host]];
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL4 host]];
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL5 host]];
```